# Paperclip crashes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have Paperclip working locally, but when I try to upload an image in production, I get the following log output and a 500 error:

```
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/Artwork20140403-10301-13bzxny.png[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/Artwork20140403-10301-13bzxny.png[0]'
[10321] + Gemfile in context: /home/deployer/apps/citycast/releases/20140331161404/Gemfile
[10240] - Worker 1 (pid: 10321) booted, phase: 0
```

It was saying it couldn't find the identify command, but that went away after I installed ImageMagick. Using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, Rubinius 2.2.5, Puma, Nginx and Rails 4.0.2.

What is going on here? How can I get Paperclip working?

Comment: What's the current error then?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your asking? I don't see a clear error in the log, and from the web I just get a generic 500 error.

Comment: Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a crash in rbx: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3002#issuecomment-39524268